# How can I find the n-th '<' symbol containing word in an XML-like text file?

Tags: linux, text-processing

I have an XML-like text file, which cannot be parsed with an XML parser due to XML violations:

```
<note>
<to>Tove</to>
<from>Jani</from>
<heading>Reminder</heading>
<body>Don't forget me this weekend!</body>
</note>
```

I just want to cut the word after `n` th tag open `<` in a file. The file should be in XML-grammar, which means lines can vary.

My expected output would be,

```
1  -  note
2  -  to
3  -  /to
4  -  from
5  -  /from
6  -  heading
7  -  /heading
8  -  body
9  -  /body
10 -  /note
```

Comment: This task is far from trivial: consider that your input xml structure has arbitrary nested levels: `<note>
<to><to_1><to_1_1>to_child1_1</to_1_1><to_1_2>to_child2_2</to_1_2></to_1><to_2>to_child2</to_2></to>
<from>Jani</from><heading>Reminder</heading></note>` What should be the **5**th node in such case?

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest Updated My question to clarify the requirment

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest Changed the title.Hope now it looks better

Comment: Your requirements say you're only interested in opening tags but your example suggests you are also interested in closing tags. What about self-closing tags? And what is a "word" - do you mean any valid XML name, including colons?

Comment: Also, I don't understand all the solutions, but I think they might not behave the way you want if there are attributes in the start tags. (But since you haven't said what you want, perhaps you don't care.)

Comment: @ThomasWeller Sorry, texts in comments that clarifies the question should be moved into the question. Comments do not really count.   If the question says "I have an XML file", then it should be tagged with the XML tag.

Comment: @ThomasWeller I approved the edit with minor modifications.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**`grep`** + **`awk`** solution:

```
grep -Eo '<[^<>]+>' input.xml | awk '{ gsub(/[<>]/,""); printf "%-3s - %s\n", NR, $0 }'
```

The output:

```
1   - note
2   - to
3   - /to
4   - from
5   - /from
6   - heading
7   - /heading
8   - body
9   - /body
10  - /note
```

---

Or with single GNU **`awk`** command:

```
awk -v FPAT='</?[^<>]+>' '{ for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) printf "%-3s - %s\n", ++c, $i }' input.xml
```

Comment: @Uchiha_Itachi, you're welcome. You may also try my second GNU awk one-liner

Comment: @user32929 You are exactly right. Here i am stuck with a non-xml file which was created to be a xml file. Some how it errored and can't parse it. Thank you for your response.

Comment: Unfortunately there are a lot of people trying to write XML without using a proper library and getting it wrong, forcing the recipients to parse the bad XML with using a proper library either. If these people were plumbers or electricians they would lose their licence to practice.

Answer (score 3):

Note: This answer was written before the user explained that the XML was not well formed.  I'm leaving it here as it may possibly help others.

---

[XMLStarlet](http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/)
is able to produce the element structure of XML documents:

```
$ xml el file.xml
note
note/to
note/from
note/heading
note/body
```

This is different from your expected output, but may be enough for what you want to achieve.

It is also able to convert the XML to PYX, which shows the opening and closing tags on separate lines:

```
$ xml pyx file.xml
(note
-\n
(to
-Tove
)to
-\n
(from
-Jani
)from
-\n
(heading
-Reminder
)heading
-\n
(body
-Don't forget me this weekend!
)body
-\n
)note
```

From this, it's easy to get exactly the output you are after:

```
$ xml pyx file.xml | sed -n -e 's/^(//p' -e 's/^)/\//p'| nl
     1  note
     2  to
     3  /to
     4  from
     5  /from
     6  heading
     7  /heading
     8  body
     9  /body
    10  /note
```

The `sed` instructions removes lines not starting with either `(` or `)` and replaces these characters according to how you specified it in the question.  The `nl` utility puts line number on lines.

---

XMLStarlet is sometimes installed as `xmlstarlet` rather than `xml`.

Answer (score 3):

```
$ awk -F"[<>]" '{for(i=2;i<=NF;i+=2){print ++j" - "$i}}' input.xml
1 - note
2 - to
3 - /to
4 - from
5 - /from
6 - heading
7 - /heading
8 - body
9 - /body
10 - /note
```

Answer (score 2):

here is an quite easy method to answer your question on extracting openning tags... but your example ask also for closing ones .... this seems nosense because a closed one is open of course....   do you really need also closed ones but if you wanna control xml format but the use a tool like xmllint ....

```
bash-4.4$ cat > toto
<note>
<to>Tove</to>
<from>Jani</from>
<heading>Reminder</heading>
<body>Don't forget me this weekend!</body>
</note> 
bash-4.4$ awk '{
match($0,/<\/.*>/); 
b=substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH); 
 if(b)
    {a[++i]=b}
     } 
END{
  {for(k in a)
    {c[a[k]]=k}
 } 
 {for(u in c)
  {gsub(/\//,X,u);print u}
 }
   }' toto | sed 's/</- /;s/>//' | cat -n
     1  - body
     2  - note
     3  - to
     4  - heading
     5  - from
bash-4.4$ rm toto
```

or to keep all & using sed only for fun :

```
bash-4.4$ sed -e  's/>\(.*\)</></;s/>/\n/g;s/</- /g' toto | sed '/^$/ d' | cat -n
     1  - note
     2  - to
     3  - /to
     4  - from
     5  - /from
     6  - heading
     7  - /heading
     8  - body
     9  - /body
    10  - /note
    11   
bash-4.4$
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's an XQuery solution just in case you want something that works on ANY XML, even awkward XML containing comments, DTDs, self-closing elements, etc.

```
declare function local:f($e) {
  $e / (name(), local:f(*), ('/' || name()))
};
for $tag at $p in local:f(/*)
return ($p || ' - ' || $tag || '&#xa;')
```